# Type: SoapFault Message: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: The fault message 'tns:GetPolicyDetailFaultDetail' must have a single part

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

Message: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: The fault message 'tns:GetPolicyDetailFaultDetail' must have a single part

Comment: Please have a look at below comments:

Comment: Sharing the WSDL will be helpful to assist further.